# Tag for "number needed to treat" and "number needed to harm"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

I see we have no tag for number needed to treat or number needed to harm.  Am I missing some tag synonym or should I create a new tag?

Comment: We usually do not create new tags to anticipate questions: tags emerge from the keywords applied to existing questions.  Are you suggesting there are questions that need such a tag?

Comment: This search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22number+needed+to+treat%22+is%3Aquestion only yields 5 Qs so I am not sure such a tag is really needed. But I don't know much about epidemiology.

Comment: Well, I just asked such a question.  It's not my area of expertise, but I suspect that there are other such questions.

Comment: If you asked a question about this subject and feel that a particular string would be a useful tag, then by all means apply the tag.  That's how tagging is supposed to work and that's all it takes to create a new tag.

Comment: There is an existing tag, it is named "[tag:nnt]". It appears I created in in December '12. It currently has 2 threads. We could add @amoeba's 3 others, make it a synonym of your new tag, or just get rid of it.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.  I think making it a synonym is best.

Comment: @PeterFlom, do you have a preference re which is the master tag?

Comment: @gung I would suggest the long one. I think the fact that Peter overlooked the short one speaks for itself.

Comment: @gung  I agree with Amoeba.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There <s>is</s> *was* an existing tag named `[nnt]` (used in two questions). I made it a synonym of new tag [number-needed-to-treat](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-needed-to-treat) and merged them.

I also created an excerpt and a wiki for it.